# Can I use third party PhoneGap plugin on a web page using iOS Safari browser?

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an application targeted only for iOS device(for now) using PhoneGap library and HTML5. This application is going to be only a web page accessed through iOS Safari browser. I am going to use certain features like accessing accelerometer, geolocation, contacts etc of iOS device using PhoneGap library.

1. Will I get access to all these features without installing anything on the device.
2. I want to understand how does PhoneGap get access to native features
   of the device by just using JavaScript only?
3. I see there are several useful plugins written for PhoneGap library.
   Can I simply use those plugins(js files) into my page without
   installing anything on the device? E.g PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin?

Comment: -> phonegap is a UIWebview in iOS app

Comment: I am not talking about iOS app but as a web page running in Safari browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I get access to all these features without installing anything on the device.

You will have to build as a native ios app and install it to the device.

> I want to understand how does PhoneGap get access to native features of the device by just using JavaScript only?

Phonegap provides a Javascript interface to access hardware features which are actually Objective-C functions. If you look at Phonegap source you'll see a lot of Objective-C code. So it's not only Javascript.

> I see there are several useful plugins written for PhoneGap library. Can I simply use those plugins(js files) into my page without installing anything on the device? E.g PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin?

No. They have to be inside an iOS app to be able to work.

Comment: If you say that PhoneGap has lot of Objective-C code then how can a browser compile and execute Objective-C?

Comment: Browser doesn't execute Objective-C. In every Phonegap iOS app, there is an internal browser called UIWebView. UIWebView is the same browser with Safari but without menus and toolbars. There are some other differences too, but i can't mention them all. On this webview you can open web pages and execute Javascript. It also has a special method called `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` and using this method, you can invoke Objective-C methods; therefore access device features. The whole Phonegap framework is built on this functionality.

Comment: In that case if I use PhoneGap in a plain html page and try to access it in Chrome iOS browser it should not work?

Comment: It certainly won't work because it won't be able to communicate with native methods.

Comment: So that means we should use PhoneGap only to create native apps and not web apps running in a browser, right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what your after is a way to access the features of an APP only through the browser.

You can access some things using HTML5 e.g.:

- Geo location http://html5demos.com/geo
- Accelerometer http://menscher.com/teaching/woaa/examples/html5_accelerometer.html
- Video Embedding http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp